# Why box-sizing doesn't work for radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a custom [radio button](http://codepen.io/erm0l0v/pen/ZGrLzX), but I can't understand why `box-sizing` doesn't work.

Chrome: [image: radio button Chrome]

FireFox: [image: radio button FireFox]

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="a"/>
<input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="a"/>
<input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="a"/>
<input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="a"/>
<input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="a"/>
```

CSS:

```
.radio-btn {
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  transition: .2s border-color;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-btn:checked {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #000;
}
.radio-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #000;
}
.radio-btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u86xboqd/

Comment: Can you include your code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You set your width and height in your .radio-btn css to 0. If you set each to 12px (to match your other styles) I think it will look the way you want it to.

```
.radio-btn {
  width: 12px;  
  height: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to determine without seeing code (not everyone can access codepen) but it may be because you also need to set `display` on the element to a block calculable value (so it respects height/width), e.g:

```
input{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You may also wish to check the relevant [compatability](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Comment: Thank you. I added code to question and copied it to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u86xboqd/). I didn't know about problems with *CodePen*.